# How to mock POST on Karma test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I dont know how to normal mock POST in Karma tests.How to check is post correct in test? How about to create a mock object and push him this pushData? Is it normal practice?

```
   it('POST', function () {
        expect(serv.addNew).toBeDefined();

        $httpBackend.when('POST', '/addnew').respond(200);

        $httpBackend.flush();

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$httpBackend.expectPOST('/addnew').respond(200)` which should fail if the post isn't satisfied (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#request-expectations-vs-backend-definitions))